# Translucent UINavigationBar ignoring view controller

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When swiping from the left, to go to the previous view controller, the navigation bar (and the tool bar) behave as if the top view controller has been removed, and will only blur the content of the previous view (the same thing happens when pushing some of the view controllers). This only happens for some controllers.

P.S. I tried doing some screenshots, but to my surprise, in them the navigation bar is as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Set CustomNavigationBar to all our navigation bars in storyboard, make sure it's not navigation controller.

Created CustomNavigationBar{m,h} or add this to AppDelegate file.

```
@interface CustomNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
@end

@implementation CustomNavigationBar

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    self.translucent = NO;
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    self.translucent = NO;
    return self;
}

@end
```